# How to get part of href= value from a string value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string value that holds a hyperlink. I want only the value after url which is: http://start.somesite.net/media/videos/flash/12345.flv . The value after url= is dynamic so how i can grab that dynamic value and put it as variable?

this is the input string value:

```
 <h4>
        <a href="http://www.somesite.com/season/?url=http://start.somesite.net/media/videos/flash/12345.flv"
    target="_blank">Download Episode 3</a>
```

Comment: Wow, surprised how many people are treating this as a DOM element when it says "this is the input string value:"

Comment: so the input string is broken html? (h4 not closed in the example)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var url = href.match(/url=(.+)/)[1]
```

Comment: url= doesn't exist in the input string

Comment: where does it say `url=`? `<h4>
        <a href="http://www.somesite.com/season/?url=http://start.somesite.net/media/videos/flash/12345.flv"
    target="_blank">Download Episode 3</a>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery try this:

```
   var link=$('#id_of_the_tag_a').attr('href');
   var linkSplitted=link.split('?url=');
   var final=linkSplitted[1];
```

If u want you can go [here](http://jsfiddle.net/corvallo/ZGxMe/4/) to see the result

Comment: The index in jsFiddle is [1]. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

`var url = input_str.match(/url=([^"]+)"/)[1];`

Comment: Actually, he's looking for a part after url= not href=.

Comment: It happens to all of us sometimes. (I wasn't the one who down voted you btw)

Comment: Thanks to brian cray and the rest.brian cray your solution gave me the flv url i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:
Give your  a tag one id.

```
var yourTag = document.getElementsById("your_tag_id"); //Get ref to your tag
var str = yourTag.getAttribute("href"); //Get the entire url
var arr = str.split("="); //Break in two parts.
str = arr[1]; //Take the second part.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turning the string into an actual anchor makes working with url strings a breeze

```
var div = ​docu​ment.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.somesite.com/season/?url=http://start.somesite.net/media/videos/flash/12345.flv" target="_blank">Download Episode 3</a>'​​​​​​​​​​​

var a = div.querySelectorAll('a');
alert(a[0].search.split('=')[1]);
```

​
I like this method because it allows you to get all kinds of information if you ever need it:

```
a[0].protocol
a[0].hostname
a[0].hash
a[0].port
a[0].innerText
```

Comment: +1 This would be an elegant solution if the input string was regular html (not broken as in the example). And split('?url=') might work even better.